# Seemingly Valid Table Row and Table Data not displaying in Table Body

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm following along with a [Dynamic Table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri5Nqe_IK50) tutorial in HTML, JS, and CSS and I cannot figure out why my table data wrapped in HTML is not doing what is expected.

I'm new to HTML, it's hard to figure out what I might be missing.  (Note that the youtube dude's code does not *seem* to be available for a quick copy paste - I copied line by line).

The table displays properly, with borders and headers shown as expected.  And I believe the function `loadTableData` is valid and should put expected `personData` into the table.  But all I see is the hardcoded output, not the output I want from the function.

Since it is hard for me to know which pieces of the code are relevant context to my issue, I've included all of the code at the bottom

Browser output:

[image]

Console logs:

```
<tr><td>John</td><td>36</td></tr><tr><td>Jane</td><td>55</td></tr>
youtubeTutorial.html:36 window.onload ran
```

Code:

```
<html>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }

    th {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    let sortDirection = false;
    let personData = [
      {
        name: "John",
        age: 36,
      },
      {
        name: "Jane",
        age: 55,
      },
    ];


    window.onload = () => {
      loadTableData(personData);
      console.log("window.onload ran")
    };

    function loadTableData(personData) {
      const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableData");
      let dataHtml = "";

      for (let person of personData) {
        dataHtml += `<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>`;
      }
      tableBody.innerHtml = dataHtml;
      console.log(dataHtml);
      
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>    
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a spelling mistake in your JS. Right in the second to last line of code:

`tableBody.innerHtml = dataHtml;`
should be:
`tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;`

JS is case-sensitive.